# How to get last Windows update date of Server 2016 and Server 2012 R2 remotely?

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, wmi

I am attempting to automatically check the date Windows Updates were last installed on a Windows Server 2012 machine and a Server 2016 machine from a remote machine. I can't seem to find any consistent way of doing so. I can use the Windows Update DLL (COM API), but I've only been able to do that locally, not remotely. I can use WMI, with the Windows Update Root, and it will list the updates for 2012 R2 and I can grab the latest one and use its date, but I don't get search info like I do from the COM api, like when it was last searched, and last successful install, and if there are available uninstalled updates. Also, the WMI root for Windows Update doesn't work for 2016. There's a registry key for 2012 R2 as well, but that also doesn't work for 2016, and doesn't provide enough information.

Preferably, I can get this in WMI somewhere and I just need to look somewhere else I'm missing. If not, I need some kind of remote solution to get the update information.

Comment: Are you looking for something like WSUS Offline?